# Backup all apks from device using adb: why this loop in bash script doesn't work?

Tags: adb, bash

You can do `adb shell pm list packages`, and after reading through the list, do an `adb shell pm path "com.yourpackage"` to get the full path and do a simply `adb pull`.

Fact is: I want to automate this. I thought about a really simple bash script:

```
for apk in $(adb shell pm list packages | sed 's/package://g' | sort); do
    # If you just do an echo, IT WORKS
    # echo $apk
    # But here it doesn't work
    adb shell pm path $apk
done
```

But that simply doesn't work. It seems that "$apk" becomes *lost* or something and nothing is shown in that snippet. I don't know if it's a subshell problem, or some peculiarity when using variables that got through an adb shell.

Should I create a script apks.sh just using `pm list`, for and such, push it to my device, run `adb shell` only once and execute apks.sh?

Comment: Try enclosing the parameters in quotes: `adb shell "pm path $apk"` and see if that works. Quoting it such makes clear the entire thing should be passed to `adb shell`. Without the quotes, it's not clear whether the `$apk` is 2nd param to `pm` or 5th param to `adb` ;)

Comment: The culprit is that `pm list packages`, just as `pm path [PACKAGE]`, results in the output being preceded by the "**package:**" string. A way to circumvent this would be to iterate through the `pm list packages` with something like the following: `for i in $(pm list packages); do`. Then, inside the loop, you'll define a variable `var` with the content of `i`, such as in: `var=$i`. Next, you'll trim the "**package:**" with `var="${var#p*:}"`, which will return the package name. After that, pass `var` through `pm path`, as in: `pm path $var`, and trim "**package:**" once more.

Comment: Regarding your question, I guess that the variable `apk` belongs to the Linux terminal only. At line 4, you're trying to pass `apk` to the `pm` as if it were an Android shell variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because adb  adds carriage return in the output. You can read [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225750/105083) for more info on that.

All of you've to do is remove the carriage return. Here's the tweaked script of yours:

```
#!/bin/bash

for package in $(adb shell pm list packages | tr -d '\r' | sed 's/package://g'); do
    apk=$(adb shell pm path $package | tr -d '\r' | sed 's/package://g');
    echo "Pulling $apk";
    adb pull -p "$apk";
done
```

You can use `-p` with `adb pull` if only you've version 1.0.32 or above of adb. `sort` is not needed, as I see it.

Answer (score 3):

I derived a one liner bash command from [Firelord's awesome answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139086/backup-all-apks-from-device-using-adb-why-this-loop-in-bash-script-doesnt-work#139099):

```
for package in $(adb shell pm list packages -3 | tr -d '\r' | sed 's/package://g'); do apk=$(adb shell pm path $package | tr -d '\r' | sed 's/package://g'); echo "Pulling $apk"; adb pull -p $apk "$package".apk; done
```

Changes/Improvements from original version:

- Backups only 3rd party apps, coz I don't see the point of backing up built-in apps. However, if you wanna backup system apps too, just skip the `-3` flag.
- Renames all apks to their package names instead of overwriting the same `base.apk` package in Android 6.0 "Marshmallow" and above.

Comment: This solution was failing to account for apk bundles where multiple APKs were returned per package, and I wireless debugging kept disconnecting for me (Galaxy Watch6) so I wanted to skip files that were already downloaded. ChatGPT to the rescue. https://chat.openai.com/share/cdf380e0-cd73-4630-8b3e-7233cec7c2cb. Pretty incredible, it did the job perfectly.